# How to auto-increment id field of mongodb with golang mgo driver?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am new to mongodb and golang. In one of my project i want to connect mongo with go. I am using mgo.v2 driver for connecting mongo with go. My question is:
How can i auto-increment the _id field of my document so that whenever i try to perform POST operation, it should auto increment the _id field of the document ?
I want to implement something similar to "FindAndModify" function but i don't see this function in go. 
This is what i want to try in go. 
[Auto increment id in mongodb](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)

```
    type count struct {
        ID  string `bson:"_id"`
        Seq int    `bson:"seq"`
    }

    var doc count

    func get NextSequence(name string) int{
    change := mgo.Change{
            Update:    collection.Update(count{ID: "userid"}, bson.M{"$inc": count{Seq: 1}}),
            ReturnNew: true,
        }

        _, err1 := collection.Find(bson.M{}).Apply(change, &doc)
       return doc.Seq
   }

    func main(){
        fmt.Println(getNextSequence("userid"))
        fmt.Println(getNextSequence("userid"))
        doc2 := msg{ID: getNextSequence("userid"), Name: "Sarah"}
        doc3 := msg{ID: getNextSequence("userid"), Name: "Sarah2"}
    }
```

I tried the above code, but the value of Seq does not seem to increment.It gives me 0 everytime i make a call to the function.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Auto-incrementing in MongoDB tends to be a bad practice because it doesn't scale well. It kind of defeats the purpose of using it. There's a reason why the default is not an auto-incrementing primary key value. Is there something you have in mind that you want to achieve that can only be done by auto-incrementing the ids?

Comment: I could not agree more with @WillC . Furthermore: `_id` is immutable. When you "change" it, you effectively create a new document. In the case you really need a counter (for example for optimistic locking), you should use  the `$inc` operator on a field which is *not* `_id`.

Answer (score 4):

According to the mgo package documentation, you can use [Query.Apply](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Query.Apply) for that. I haven't tried it myself, but the example given there seems to already do what you want to achieve:

```
 change := mgo.Change{
         Update: bson.M{"$inc": bson.M{"n": 1}},
         ReturnNew: true,
 }
 info, err = col.Find(M{"_id": id}).Apply(change, &doc)
 fmt.Println(doc.N)
```

Comment: i tried the same thing but the field does not seem to increment.

Comment: Helped me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the below one

Declare one more variable name `var total_doc int'`

Then do `collection.Find(bson.M{}).Count(total_doc)` this will return the total number of document your have in you mongodb database.

After add `doc.Seq = total_doc + 1`.This will keep on incrementing the sequence value whenever a new document gets added.

Hope this could help you

Comment: This does not provide safety if 2 concurrent goroutines query the total count and attempt to insert a new document, they will use the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

Might be late but you can also use [night-codes/mgo-ai](https://github.com/night-codes/mgo-ai) package to manage your sequences.

I personally used this, I created a separate `sequences` collection to store the incremented values. I also kept the `_id` field and had a separate `id` field for my `sequence` value.

From its `README.md`:

```
    package main

    import (
        "github.com/night-codes/mgo-ai"
        "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
        "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
    )

    func main() {
        session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        // connect AutoIncrement to collection "counters"
        ai.Connect(session.DB("example-db").C("counters"))

        // ...

        // use AutoIncrement
        session.DB("example-db").C("users").Insert(bson.M{
            "_id":   ai.Next("users"),
            "login": "test",
            "age":   32,

    }
```